# SBS2008 : can't have a mailbox accessible from outside?

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2008

We have a SBS2008 server with 9 users using the embeeded Exchange. The MX record points to this server. This works fine.

We want 2 remote users to also have a mailbox on this server. The consultant say we can't because SBS don't allow to have remote users for Exchange. He may be right but seems very strange to me. I don't find anything related to that.

I don't want to touch this server for political reasons. So I can't do any test.

Can anyone confirm if Exchange on SBS2008 can or can't be reached from outside ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange on SBS 2008 allows remote access to mailboxes using OWA  (Outlook Web Access).

If you port-foward 25/80/443 on your firewall to internal LAN IP of your SBS server, then you can access your OWA URL from this link

https://mail.domain.com/owa (replace mail.domain.com with your external FQDN)

You can test this internally by going to `https://192.168.1.10/owa`
where 192.168.1.10 is the internal LAN IP of exchange server

There are additional steps to configure OWA. You can see a good guide here:
http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/05/sbs-2008-setup-checklist-v111.html

Comment: You can also support Activesync for smartphones and Outlook Anywhere for the full Outlook client from outside the firewall.  Basically your consultant is wrong and it's all available from the Web URL.  More OA info for SBS 2008: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794265(v=ws.10).aspx